# Python String encode method

Tags: python, unicode

In Python, there is an `encode` method in unicode strings to encode from unicode to byte string. There is a `decode` method in string to do the reverse.

But I'm confused what the `encode` method in string for?

Comment: Take a look at this presentation 'Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified' http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: I've seen that. It doesn't explain my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's useful for non-text codecs.

```
>>> 'Hello, world!'.encode('hex')
'48656c6c6f2c20776f726c6421'
>>> 'Hello, world!'.encode('base64')
'SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==\n'
>>> 'Hello, world!'.encode('zlib')
'x\x9c\xf3H\xcd\xc9\xc9\xd7Q(\xcf/\xcaIQ\x04\x00 ^\x04\x8a'
```

Comment: Wow, it even works if the encoded string is incompatible with the default encoding! That must mean it doesn't always decode the string to unicode first...

Comment: Ok, so looks like it'll decode to unicode if we encode to one of the character encodings. Strange.

Answer (score 5):

It first decodes to Unicode using the default encoding, then encodes back to a byte string.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
>>> '\xc4'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\x84'
```

Here, `'\xc4'` is Latin-1 for Ä and `'\xc3\x84'` is UTF-8 for Ä.